# HTML5 video player stuck at poster

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make my own custom controls for HTML5 video. So far I've only implemented a play/pause button, but I've run into a problem.

The video does not play at startup, so when I click the custom play button, I can hear the video's audio - but the video is stuck at the poster image.

I have a JSFiddle of my demo with the problem (try clicking the play button): https://jsfiddle.net/9gpg6gbd/

This is the snippet of the play/pause button's code:

```
// Initialize play button
if (video.paused) {
    container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "&#9658;"
} else {
    container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "| |"
}
container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
        container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "| |"
    } else {
        video.pause();
        container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "&#9658;"
    }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm stumped on this one.

Comment: See the last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to errors:

1. Do not add your HTML element inside the video tag.
2. Do not hold video element in variable and change it's place.

## Solution #1:

Replace your `video.play()` with the selector.

```js
function initializeControls(container, video) {
 // Initialize play button
 if (video.paused) {
        container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "&#9658;"
    } else {
        container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "| |"
    }
    container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").addEventListener("click", function(){
     if (document.body.querySelectorAll(".supervideo")[0].paused) {
      document.body.querySelectorAll(".supervideo")[0].play();
      container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "| |"
     } else {
       document.body.querySelectorAll(".supervideo")[0].pause();
      container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "&#9658;"
     }
 });
}

function createVidElement() {
 var videos = document.body.querySelectorAll(".supervideo");

 [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) {
  // Hide controls if the player has tdem
  if (video.hasAttribute("controls")) {
   video.controls = false;
  }
  // Create video container
  var container = document.createElement('div');
     container.setAttribute("class", "supervideo-container");
     video.parentElement.appendChild(container);
     container.appendChild(video);
     // Created media controls
     container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="supervideo-controls"><tr> <td><button id="supervideo-playbutton" type="button">&#215;</button></td> <td>Time</td> <td>Scrollbar</td> <td>Mute button</td> <td>Volume</td> <td>Fullscreen</td> </tr></table>';
     initializeControls(container, video);
 });
}

createVidElement();
```

```html
<video width="100%" controls class="supervideo">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" />
</video>
```

## Solution #2:

Inside the foreach you changed the position of the `<Video>` tag. you appended it to the new container. after this line your selector will be invalid, you have to reassign your selector.

```js
function initializeControls(container, video) {
 // Initialize play button
 if (video.paused) {
        container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "&#9658;"
    } else {
        container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "| |"
    }
    container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").addEventListener("click", function(){
     if (video.paused) {
      video.play();
      container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "| |"
     } else {
      video.pause();
      container.querySelector("#supervideo-playbutton").innerHTML = "&#9658;"
     }
 });
}

function createVidElement() {
 var videos = document.body.querySelectorAll(".supervideo");

 [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) {
  // Hide controls if the player has tdem
  if (video.hasAttribute("controls")) {
   video.controls = false;
  }
  // Create video container
  var container = document.createElement('div');
     container.setAttribute("class", "supervideo-container");
     video.parentElement.appendChild(container);
     
      //container.appendChild(video);
     
      // Created media controls
     container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="supervideo-controls"><tr> <td><button id="supervideo-playbutton" type="button">&#215;</button></td> <td>Time</td> <td>Scrollbar</td> <td>Mute button</td> <td>Volume</td> <td>Fullscreen</td> </tr></table>';
     initializeControls(container, video);
 });
}

createVidElement();
```

```html
<video width="100%" controls class="supervideo">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Unable to pause video

Comment: See solution #2

Comment: The same problem with with video selector, I forget to change the `if(video. paused)` with `document.body.querySelectorAll(".supervideo")[0].paused`

Comment: Thank you so much, solution #2 fixes my problem.